# Baking Bevel Shader Produces Artifacts Along Mesh Edges

Tags: texture-baking, bevel

This is my first time using the bevel shader to bake rounded edges, and it seems like it produces a bevel effect even on smooth shaded edges. This creates a grid effect along all the polygon edges. On the actual baked normal map this effect is extremely subtle, but it's very noticable on glossy materials. [image]
[[image: ][1]]
[image]

I so far couldn't detect any error with the baking setup. Since there apparently isn't an angle limit option for the bevel node, this might just be an unavoidable property of the shader, but is there any way to circumvent this? I managed to filter the affected parts of the texture out in Substance Painter, by using an edge filter, but this seems like a thing where you shouldn't need a workaround. Since I have also not found any other post about this problem, i was wondering whether I'm doing something wrong here.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I have this alike problem before when i using 3.3.6LTS,and i have no idea how to fix.Then i change blender version to 3.5.1,the spots gone...so i think it might be old version bug?or the new version bake better.